# If I want all cylinders' height to be a fixed value after rotation, how would I calculate the original height?

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I am new to WebGL and Three.js. If I want all cylinders' height to be a fixed value after rotation, how would I calculate the original height?

Here is what I want: I have several Cylinders and I put the original point of every cylinder as the center of bottom, and cylinders were connected by sphere, and cylinders will rotate by x, y and z according to the parameters. The cylinder height is 30, but after rotation the height in y axis is less than 30. What should I do if I want the height in y axis is still 30 after rotation? I need to recalculate the cylinder height before rotation, can I get some advice on how to do this? Thanks very much for any help.  Anyone could help?      :)

```
var cyliderHeight = 30;

var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( topRadius, botRadius, cyliderHeight, 16 );
cylinderGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, cyliderHeight/2, 0 ) );

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylinderGeometry, material );
cylinder.position.set( positionX, positionY, positionZ);    

group.add( cylinder );                              
cylinder.rotation.x = NaturalIncrease  / 100000;
cylinder.rotation.y = year * 4 / 10000;
cylinder.rotation.z = NetOverseasMigration  / 100000;

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry(topRadius, 20, 20), material );
var point = new THREE.Vector3( 0, cyliderHeight, 0 );
point.applyEuler( cylinder.rotation );
sphere.position.set( point.x + positionX, point.y + positionY, point.z + positionZ );
```

Comment: Could you use trig functions? 30=sin(theta)*startHeight

Comment: Hi, but height 30 is the fixed height I want after rotate in x, and then rotate in y and then rotate in z, will the trig functions work?

Comment: theta in that function would be the angle off of a "height" normal, I don't know how you have your dimensions set up, but it should work however.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But if the cylinder rotated in x, then y, then z, do you have any idea how to calculate the "theta"?

Comment: Anyone could help? I don't know what to do to solve it. Still looking for solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotations about the y axis won't matter. You can think of the two other components of rotation in two different steps, and apply the elongation twice over.